# Excel Macro for Inserting a Blank Row Whenever a Value in a Column Changes

Tags: excel

I have been using the following macro in Excel 2016 to insert a blank row whenever a value in selected column B changes:

```
Sub InsertDividerRows()
'
' InsertDividerRows Macro
' Insert a blank row whenever a value in a sorted list changes
'

'
    Selection.LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "B").Value <> Cells(i - 1, "B").Value Then Rows(i).Insert
    Next i
End Sub
```

Problem 1: Today, this macro has suddenly stopped working. I get a Run Time Error (438), and the "Selection.LastRow" line is highlighted when debugging.  (I rebooted my PC without success.)

Problem 2: I would like to modify this macro so that it functions for any column range I highlight (not just entire column B).

Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `LastRow` is a variable, get rid of the `Selection` in front of it.

Comment: For your second question, look up how to loop through a range of columns.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your Problem 1 is in the narrative for your Problem 2. You've added Selection in front of .LastRow = ... as a beginning to make the sub procedure work for any column selected.

I'll assume that a change from a value to a blank cell or a blank cell to a value should not initiate an inserted row.

```
Sub InsertDividerRows()
'
' InsertDividerRows Macro
' Insert a blank row whenever a value in a sorted list changes
'
    dim c as long, i as long

    with selection.parent

        c = selection.cells(1).column

        for i=.cells(.rows.count, c).end(xlup).row to 2 step -1
            if application.counta(.range(.cells(i, c), .cells(i-1, c))) = 2 and _
               .cells(i, c).value <> .cells(i-1, c).value then
                .rows(i).entirerow.insert
            end if
        next i

    end with

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfection !!!  Thanks so much !!!  (I am a novice at writing macros... thanks for patiently replying to my "dumb" question!)